# Android API Level 31 not showing in VS after updating build tools?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019, android-sdk-manager, targetsdkversion

I am looking to update my targetSDK version to Level 31, as per a warning I saw on the Google Play Store. But my Visual Studio warns that I don't have it installed. So I went to the Tools tab in SDK Manager and installed Android SDK Build-Tools 31 (31.0.0). However, Android 12 (Level 31) still does not show in the SDK manager to install.

What could I be missing? I tried searching on this and they mentioned updating the build tools which I did. I also looked at Android documentation, but they talk about using Android Studio (for native Android), not Visual Studio for Xamarin.Android.

This is for a Xamarin.Android project. I am on Visual Studio Professional 2019 version 16.9.6 if it matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is upgrading the Visual Studio to the version 2022, because the Android Api Level 31 has a dependency on JDK 11, which has some compatibility issues with Visual Studio 2019.

But if you really want to use Visual Studio 2019, you can check [this link](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/wiki/JDK-11-Warning) and install the JDK 11 follow up it.

Now the newest Android Api Level is 33, and it can be used in the Visual Studio 2022 newest version. So I really suggest you update the Visual Studio.